# Characterisation of surjectivity resembling one for injectivity

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

For a function $f : A \to B$ we have the following equivalences:

- $f$ is injective,
- for all $X, Y \subseteq A$ we have $f(X \cap Y) = f(X) \cap f(Y)$,
- for all $X \subseteq Y \subseteq A$ we have $f(X \setminus Y) = f(X) \setminus f(Y)$.

> Does there exists a corresponding characterisation of surjectivity?

For all other characterisations of those two properties I can find corresponding formulations, for example the following is equivalent to injectivity (with $(f\circ g)(x) := f(g(x))$):

i) $|f^{-1}(\{b\})| \le 1$ for all $b \in B$,

ii) there exists $g : B \to A$ such that $g \circ f = \mbox{id}_A$

iii) If $f \circ h = f \circ g$ then $h = g$.

iv) for all $A \subseteq X$ we have $f^{-1}(f(A)) = A$.

And those properties characterising surjectivity correspond to the above:

i) $|f^{-1}(\{b\})| \ge 1$ for all $b \in B$,

ii) there exists $g : B \to A$ such that $f \circ g = \mbox{id}_B$,

iii) If $h \circ f = g \circ f$ then $h = g$,

iv) for all $B \subseteq Y$ we have $f(f^{-1}(B)) = B$.

So in those list for every characterisation of one property I can find another characterisation which closely resembles it, but for the characterisation of injectivity in terms of preservation of set operations I cannot find a characteristation of surjectivity?

Comment: A natural variant on the second dot point is that $f$ of the empty intersection is the empty intersection, i.e. $f(A) = B$, which is just surjectivity. Good question, by the way.